# How to combine full_text_search with unaccent using Sequel gem?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, full-text-search, sequel

How can I use the method [`Sequel.full_text_search`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/Postgres/DatasetMethods.html#method-i-full_text_search) combined with the function available in PostgreSQL `unaccent` in order to return records that match the search term regardless characters with accents?

For example:

```ruby
# Given a user with first_name: Nícolas
User.full_text_search(:first_name, "nicolas").count
# Expected result to be 1, but it is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the expected result by using the class `Sequel::SQL::Function`:

```ruby
# Given a user with first_name: Nícolas
col = Sequel.qualify(:users, :first_name)
col_without_accent = Sequel::SQL::Function.new(:UNACCENT, col)
Person.full_text_search(col_without_accent, "nicolas").count
# => 1
```

We can also apply the same `unaccent` function to the term used to match results:

```ruby
Person.full_text_search(col_without_accent, Sequel::SQL::Function.new(:UNACCENT, "nícolas")).count
```